# How to reset the idleMonitor's idle counter in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `idleMonitor` in prime faces configured as below.

```
<!-- Idle Counter - 20 minutes(1200000 milliseconds) -->
<p:idleMonitor timeout="1200000" onidle="PF('idleDialog').show();" />
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
    message="You have been idle for 20 minutes and your session is expired. Please Login again."
    header="Session Expired" severity="alert" widgetVar="idleDialog" closable="false" closeOnEscape="false" >
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="text-align:center">
            <h:outputLink value="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Click Here to Login</h:outputLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

I don't know but somehow, the idleMonitor isn't resetting its value and the idleMonitor counter continues to run and right in the middle of UI while I am working, the pop-up comes and says that my session is logged out. I don't know what is wrong with the code above, but somehow, the idle counter isn't resetting when I am working on the UI.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Your trouble unknown to me, all work perfectly. Share .xhtml or  form code, i'll testing it

Comment: Does the idle values reset during server callbacks?

Comment: Try to find the real cause. Show a fully working yet minimal example that demonstrates the problem, since I cannot reproduce, there must be other parts that disturb the normal behaviour

Answer (score 0):

To manually reset idle:

```
<p:idleMonitor widgetVar="idle" timeout="300" onidle="alert('OK')" />

<p:commandButton value="reset" onclick="PF('idle').reset()" global="false"/>
```

As well you can that:

```
<p:commandButton value="pause" onclick="PF('idle').pause()" />
<p:commandButton value="resume" onclick="PF('idle').resume()" />
```

Comment: I did a ````PF('idle')```` on my Firebug console and I don't see any ````pause(), reset(), resume()```` methods.

Comment: What PF version you used? I read official documentation at page 251 (PF 5.1) Client Side API of IdleMonitor. And read source code https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5.2.x/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/idlemonitor/idlemonitor.js. So?

Comment: I am referring to [this pdf documentation for 5.1](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf) and I don't see that on page 251. My version is 5.1. Also, the javascript reference you provided is for version 5.2.

Comment: Use latest version with new functional. Previous i  made a typo - version 5.2 as in link to github

Comment: There is a `reset` function on the idleMonitor; it's just not (properly) documented. It used to be in the old documentation, don't know why they removed it @divinedragon

Comment: I see the ````reset()```` in the object properties in firebug when I run ````PF('idle')````, but when I call that, it gives error.

Comment: @devinedragon: WHAT error? And the solution in this answer should not be needed. Try to find the real cause. Show a fully working yet minimal example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: This works for me. The object has the pause() function.